# ASP.NET Core (.NET 7) Storing Sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-7.0

I have a basic ASP.NET Core Web App with Razor pages (.cshtml) and I've setup a basic Session
like so:

```
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = ".SuperMemory.Session";
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});
```

and upon login after successful login i set sessions like "_isLogged" and "_Name" ( user's username )
but the issue is that the session expire the moment i refresh the site or for instance i go to the main page and so on.

I've tried multiple things like using

```
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
```

and even without it the session still expire; I've researched on google and asked multiple AI's for some sort of approach to store those sessions so they don't just expire after refresh or whenever i open new tab with the same site/url but like after 20m of idle or until logout, but i just couldn't find the best way.

Comment: I found that the sessions doesn't expire but rather the data set upon refresh or going into other page is lost.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have disabled your browser's cookies.

You can turn on it and it should be fixed.

Chrome : https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/61416?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

---

You are missing `app.UseSession();`. The order of middleware is important. Call UseSession after UseRouting and before MapRazorPages and MapDefaultControllerRoute

[image]

Official document:[Configure session state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-session-state)

**The standard usage is as follows:**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = ".SuperMemory.Session";
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
});

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();
// Add this line
app.UseSession();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();

app.Run();
```

Comment: yes i do use the `app.UseSession();` in the right order, but after i set variables for instance 

 `HttpContext.Session.SetString("_Logged", "true");`

upon refreshing the site or going on any other page like the /home or the /privacy that variable is gone @JasonPan

Comment: Hello @Trollicus, Ok, until now I can confirm the issue not related to how to use session in asp.net core.

Comment: @Trollicus You should provide the code in Program.cs  file, I need to if some middleware cause the issue. One more thing, it happened in VS2022 or in IIS ?

Comment: so i don't use neither VS2020 nor IIS thing, but rather the 'https' build config in JetBrains Rider you can find the whole Program.cs source [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/r6S0UUK9)

Comment: Dear Trollicus，could you try to run this project in vs2022? I mean we should check whether the issue related to Rider. And you also could try to upgrade your Rider to latest version an test again,many thanks

Comment: I mean I see no point in trying it in vs20202 it's basically the same, although my Rider is on the latest version as well! but I have no clue why would the session variables are being lost when i refresh the page

Comment: Hi @Trollicus If you really want to fix the issue and find the reason, it's better to provider a sample which can reproduce the issue in your side for us. Then I could try to reproduce it in my machine, if I can reproduce the issue, it means it's a code issue in the project. If it works well, it means it related to the environment.

Comment: i saw that the issue is from 'HttpContext' which as it says on the docs it is not guaranteed to keep the data trough the run

Comment: Hi @Trollicus, I have reproduce the issue and find it related to brower settings.